# Given an array of integers, how do I find out if it containts 2 elemnts of equal value. limits: complexity is O(nlog(n))

Tags: c, time-complexity

I know how to find if there are 2 equal numbers in array with a complexity of O(n^2) but someone on a forum asked to do it in O(nlog(n))

Couldn't figure it out

Comment: Hint: sorting can be done in O(nlogn).

Comment: So I can just Shell sort the array and the run a sorted search for the divertion of 0 on it?
but by doing so i run nlogn + n which means I run O(n)

Comment: Sort the array in an efficient way (there are sereval algorithms for that, I suggest you do some search). Then in one linear traversal you can find if there are duplicates, because they will be in adjacent cells in the array.

Comment: Build a hash table and  check equality on a hash collision.  On average: O(n).  Reasonable and certain O(n) solutions available select range of values.